# Graphaware REST, only 404 replies

Tags: rest, neo4j, graphaware

I'm having lots of trouble getting graphaware and the noderank module running. I'm using Neo4j 2.3.2 and the latest (2.3.2.37) release of graphaware (tried centOS, Debian and Windows, no difference). The module starts up and does its job, but I'm not able to communicate with it via REST (Neo4j's REST interface is working fine). All GET-requests are answered with 404. If I start Neo4j in console mode, there is no log stating something like "Mounted /graphaware...." etc.

Since I have not modified anything and am using (as far as I think) compatible releases, I hardly think, that I am the only one facing this problem... Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add the full configuration of your modules.

Note also, that since 2.3 release of Neo4j, there is an extra line to add in your `neo4j-server.properties` file :

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware
```

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework#upgrading-to-neo4j-23

Comment: That makes it work. I didn't get that from the documentation. Thank you so much!